# Subclass's variable's calling from parent's class

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, subclass, unityscript

I am converting PC version UnityScript game from unity3d to android mobile game,

and this works well in pc UnityScript version, but error occurs under Android platform, and should revise, but how?

```
class Stats{
   var point1 : int;
   var point2 : int;
}
class MageStats extends Stats{
   var magic1 : int;
}

var player1Stat : Stats;
```

In this case, if I write [ player1Stat.magic1 ] result error under #Pragma Strict circumstances. 
(but worked well in pc version normal javascript)

Why and how should I revise?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Unity, but can it be that, for Android, Unity limits your usage to *strict typing* instead of the usual JavaScript dynamic typing?

Comment: @Darkhogg Yes, unity limits to strict typing for android, so I should revise above code.

Answer (score 0):

Under strict typing, you can't refer to properties of subclasses of a type.

```
var player1Stat : Stats;
player1Stat.magic1
```

If you look at your code, the `Stats` class does not define `magic1`. If you want to use that property you must directly use a variable of type `MageStats` (which does define that property).